# docker-compose build: value 'devices' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, gpu

I´m trying to enable GPU access in a docker container, but when I run the command `docker-compose build` I get the next error:
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.notebook.deploy.resources.reservations value 'devices' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'
My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
services:
  notebook:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8887:8887
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/pae/
      - ./models:/home/pae/models
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /mnt/zdisk:/home/pae/data/zdisk
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: " jupyter-notebook --allow-root --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8887"
    restart: always
    image: pae_notebook:latest
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities:
                - gpu
```

Something curious, is that if I build the image without the deploy key in the .yml file and then add it to the file, it is possible to run `docker-compose up` and it uses the GPU, as I´ve checked with the `nvidia-smi` tool.
Another thing I notice is that the error message says "value 'devices'" and 'devices' is a key.

Version information:
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

I hope someone can help me, I´m a beginner in docker. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use to have this problem, was solved by updating docker-compose to v2.18.1.